# ASP.NET MVC Редактирование значения словаря Dictionary<T, string> где ключ это тип

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

В NHibernate определены следующие сущности:

```
public class Nomenclature
{
    public virtual int NomenclatureId { get; set; }
    public virtual NomenclatureType NomenclatureType { get; set; }  
    public virtual IDictionary<NomenclatureAttribute, string> Attributes { get; set; }
}
public class NomenclatureType
{
    public virtual int NomenclatureTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual string  Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Nomenclature> Nomenclatures { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NomenclatureAttribute> NomenclatureAttributes { get; set; }
    public NomenclatureType()
    {
        Nomenclatures = new HashSet<Nomenclature>();
        NomenclatureAttributes = new HashSet<NomenclatureAttribute>();
    }
}
public class NomenclatureAttribute
{
    public virtual int NomenclatureAttributeId { get; set; }
    public virtual string AttributeName { get; set; }
    public virtual string AttributeType { get; set; }
    public virtual NomenclatureType NomenclatureType { get; set; }
}
```

Они представляют собой описание модели номенклатуры в приложении. 
Описывая сущность Nomenclature сделал Controller и добавил туда Create

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(string nomenclatureType)
{
    if (nomenclatureType == null)
        return RedirectToAction("List", "Nomenclature");
    ViewData["NomenclatureAttributes"] =
        _repositoryNomenclatureType.Get(w => w.Name == nomenclatureType).NomenclatureAttributes.ToList();
    return View();
} 

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Nomenclature nomenclature)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _repositoryNomenclature.Create(nomenclature);
            return RedirectToAction("List", "Nomenclature");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes.");                                     
    }
    return View(nomenclature);
}
```

В view я перебираю все Аттрибуты номенклатуры, но пока мне удалось только создать label для всех доступных атрибутов переданного в контроллер типа номенклатуры. Как мне используя механизм привязки модели(или как-нибудь ещё) создать editor для каждого аттрибута и записать его в Model.Attributes. Где Attributes это `public virtual IDictionary<NomenclatureAttribute, string> Attributes { get; set; }`

```
@model Nomenclature
@{
ViewBag.Title = "New nomenclature";
Layout = "_Layout";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @foreach (var a in (List<NomenclatureAttribute>)ViewData["NomenclatureAttributes"])
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">@a.AttributeName</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
             **Код эдитора которого нет**
            </div>
         </div>

    }

  <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Использую Asp.net core web application (.NET Framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача была решена не самым правильны способом, но зато решена. Итак для начала я формирую ViewModel вида:

```
public class NomenclatureCreateViewModel
{
    public NomenclatureCreateViewModel()
    {
        Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        NomenclatureAttributes = new List<NomenclatureAttribute>();
    }
    public virtual int NomenclatureId { get; set; }
    public NomenclatureType NomenclatureType { get; set; }
    public List<NomenclatureAttribute> NomenclatureAttributes { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

В контроллере на Get я заполняю ViewModel данными:

```
         [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create(string type)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("List", "Nomenclature");
        }
        var nomenclature = new NomenclatureCreateViewModel
        {
            NomenclatureType = _repositoryNomenclatureType.Get(w => w.Name == type),
            NomenclatureAttributes = _repositoryNomenclatureType.Get(w=>w.Name == type).NomenclatureAttributes.ToList()
        };

        foreach (var nomenclatureAttribute in nomenclature.NomenclatureAttributes)
        {
            nomenclature.Attributes.Add(nomenclatureAttribute.AttributeName, string.Empty);
        }

        return View(nomenclature);
    }
```

Во View я использую перебор для создания Editor Для каждого значения словоря:

```
@foreach (var kvpair in Model.Attributes)
{
<div class="col-md-10">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">@kvpair.Key</label>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Attributes[kvpair.Key])
</div>
}
```

А в методе Post уже заполняю экземпляр модели данными из ВьюМодели(не нравится мне это название в этом контексте):

```
nomenclatureViewModel.NomenclatureAttributes =
    _repositoryNomenclatureType.Get(w => w.Name == nomenclatureViewModel.NomenclatureType.Name).NomenclatureAttributes.ToList();

var nomenclature = new Nomenclature();
nomenclature.NomenclatureType = _repositoryNomenclatureType.Get(w=>w.Name==nomenclatureViewModel.NomenclatureType.Name);

foreach (var attribute in nomenclatureViewModel.Attributes)
{
    nomenclature.Attributes.Add(nomenclatureViewModel.NomenclatureAttributes.Find(w=>w.AttributeName==attribute.Key), attribute.Value);
}

_repositoryNomenclature.Create(nomenclature);
return RedirectToAction("List", "Nomenclature");
```

Понятно, что это решение очень "Костыль", но как сделать правильнее? Может кто подскажет?